# Can enemies see the current keystone of Omnistone

Tags: league-of-legends

When you use Prototype: Omnistone rune, an indicator is noticeable next to your HP bar when a keystone is ready to be used. Can enemies see this keystone, or just myself/allies?

Omnistone randomly gives you one of the keystones (e.g. Conqueror or Electrocute etc.) every 40 seconds. The icon of the appropriate keystone appears to the right of your HP bar (also on top of your bottom panel). So I'm asking whether the enemy can see the currently active keystone too. The reason for asking is obvious: if the enemy sees that I have Grasp (for example), they may try to deny me an autoattack to deny me additional healing etc. However, if they cannot see the icon, they would have no idea what is activated at the moment

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more? I’m not really understanding what your asking completely

Comment: Omnistone randomly gives you one of the keystones (e.g. Conqueror or Electrocute etc.) every 40 seconds. The icon of the appropriate keystone appears to the right of your HP bar (also on top of your bottom panel). So I'm asking whether the enemy can see the currently active keystone too.
The reason for asking is obvious: if the enemy sees that I have Grasp (for example), they may try to deny me an autoattack to deny me additional healing etc. However, if they cannot see the icon, they would have no idea what is activated at the moment.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining. I don’t think they can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All players can see the keystone that's currently ready to be used by a player who uses Omnistone.

The indicator will appear just next to the Omnistone user's HP bar, and it appears the same for both allies and enemies of the Omnistone user.

Here's a screenshot of how it looks on an enemy champion:

[image: Indicator of Glacial Augment, from the view of an enemy of the Omnistone user]

Nothing changes in the visibility of this indicator. It doesn't matter if you're the user, an ally of the user, or an enemy of the user.